# Java StreamSource from file in web application project

Tags: java, xslt, stylesheet, filepath

```
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();    
                Source stylesheetSource = new StreamSource(new File("stylesheet.xsl").getAbsoluteFile());
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(stylesheetSource);
                Writer strWriter = new StringWriter();
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(strWriter);
                transformer.transform(source, result);
```

This looks for the stylesheet file from C://stylesheet.xsl but how do I get it to point to a file in my project for example /src/main/java/util/stylesheet.xsl

I've tried

```
                InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/main/webapp/stlesheets/stylesheet.xsl"); 
                Source stylesheetSource = new StreamSource(is);
                ...
```

but I get these exceptions

```
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet' 
FATAL ERROR:  'java.net.MalformedURLException' 
:null
```

EDIT:

I've tracked the ServletContext and it gives the correct context path /project_name so the error is coming from the getResourceAsStream function

The file path is /project_name/src/main/resources/stylesheet.xsl
The servletcontext path is /project_name
I'm using servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/stylesheet.xsl")
Still getting the error

```
                ServletContext sc = req.getSession().getServletContext();
                InputStream is = sc.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/stylesheet.xsl");
```

Comment: Do you have a  src/main/resources in your application? Have you tried moving the file to that folder?

Comment: I do have /src/main/resources and when I put it there I still get the exceptions

Comment: Do you have /src/main/resources in classpath i.e. inside your compile code...in webapp or war?

Comment: Yes. 
Is there any other way of doing this? 
Maybe my path is wrong? /src/main/resources/stylesheet.xsl is what I'm using at the moment

Comment: Solved it. 
Restarted eclipse and the path /stylesheet.xsl worked...